# Store a variable in an iPhone app

Tags: ios, plist

I need to store just a 1 variable somewhere in my app. I know that any app has a plist. Can I store the variable into that? or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a few values, storing it in `NSUserDefaults` is much easier.

```
int someValue = 42;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:someValue forKey:@"SomeKey"];

int myValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"SomeKey"];
```

Use the appropriate set and get methods depending on the type of value.

Please note that if you have a custom object to store, there is a lot more involved.

Comment: Thanx, that was much better than my way.

Comment: if the app crashes or user closes the app, am I gonna lose the data?

Comment: No, user defaults are persistent. Make sure you call the `synchronize` method after setting values though.

Comment: I only call `synchronize` in the app delegate's `didEnterBackground` method. However, if the app crashes, it is possible that a value set in NSUserDefaults could be lost if the OS hasn't yet auto-synchronized the values. If you have a critical value that can't be lost even if the app crashes, then calling `synchronize` after setting the value is a good idea.

Comment: I don't know what you guys mean by synchronize. If I call it, its going to be stored on the device?

Comment: @AliBZ `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`. When you call `setXXX:forKey:`, the value is in memory for some period of time. The OS eventually persists the data to a file in your app's sandbox. If your app crashes between these two events, the value will be lost. By explicitly calling the `synchronize` method, you can be sure the value won't be lost if the app crashes.